# dataTable refresh on ajax success

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the data table from the jquery plugin dataTables (http://datatables.net/) that I want to refresh upon ajax success. I tried the following code but its not working. Any help will be appreciated

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    oTable = $('#mytable').dataTable();
    var fa = 0;
    $('#submit tbody td ').click(function() {
    var gCard = $('#mytable tbody').delegate("tr", "click", rowClick);


    });
    function rowClick() {
        fa = this;
        var id  = $("td:eq(1)", this).text();
        cardNumber = $.trim(id);    
        $.ajax({
            url : 'myurltopostto',
            type : 'POST',
            data : {
                id  :   id

            },
            success : function(data) {
                oTable.fnDraw(); //wanted to update here
            },
            error : function() {
                console.log('error');
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: not sure what you mean, but after I click the submit button, I want the table to show the latest data in the table

Comment: is data returned in the ajax success? if so is it just html rows or a full html table or a full page or json or????? Can't guess what your other code is doing, or what simply sending an id to server does in your app

Comment: also you have a click handler being delegated inside another click handler , not sure what logic is there but it is likely a problem

Comment: simply sending an id deletes that record. so I want the table to be refreshed so that row does not show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use : `fnDeleteRow` which will take care of refreshing the table html and data internally, look up API details here:

http://datatables.net/ref

```
    oTable.fnDeleteRow( fa );
```

Comment: only problem with that is that if I am doing pagination, it will not bring other records that are not in the view. And if I am viewing 10 records at a time, on 9th record it will stuck and wouldnt work.

Answer (score 0):

hello my dears programers... sorry... my inglish is very bad but I help you... my following is this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function Ajax()
        {
            var
                $http,
                $self = arguments.callee;

            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                $http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                try {
                    $http = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
                } catch(e) {
                    $http = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
                }
            }

            if ($http) {
                $http.onreadystatechange = function()
                {
                    if (/4|^complete$/.test($http.readyState)) {
                        document.getElementById('ReloadThis').innerHTML = $http.responseText;
                        setTimeout(function(){$self();}, 10000);
                        $( this ).hide( "slow" );
                    }
                };
                $http.open('GET', 'cls_Noticias/last_noticias.php', true);
                $http.send(null);
            }

        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout(function() {Ajax();}, 10000);
    </script>

    <div id="ReloadThis">Espere a que la pagina se actualice!</div>

</body>
```

good life!